# как обновить recyclerview c другого Activity?

Tags: android, recyclerview

Всем привет! есть recyclerview в фрагменте и кнопка которая открывает новое Activity. В этом Activity я добавляю данные в базу sqlite и возвращаюсь опять к recyclerview, но в recyclerview список не обновляется пока не перезагружу приложение. Как обновить recyclerview с другого активити?

[image: фрагмент с recyclerview]
[image: новое активити где я добавляю данные в recyclerview]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Новое Activity следует запускать с запросом результата через

```
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE)
```

Запущенная активность при возвращении из нее должна сообщить, действительно ли были добавлены новые данные. Для этого когда добавляются данные нужно добавить что-то вроде:

```
Intent data = new Intent();
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
```

Во фрагменте с RecyclerView для получения результата от активности нужно переопределить метод onActivityResult:

```
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int result, Intent data){
    if(result == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_CODE ){
        //если данные действительно были добавлены, обновить список
        mRecyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Не забудьте во фрагменте добавить константу:

```
private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Вызвать функцию `notifyDataSetChanged()`. У меня вот такой код.

```
ArrayList<Project> projects = storage.getProjects(); 
if (mAdapter == null) {
    mAdapter = new ProjectAdapter(projects);
    mProjectsRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
} else {
    mAdapter.setProjects(projects);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```